# Compliment of a Set to Get Out of Jail in Monopoly

Tags: probability

I'm reading a web-page that states the probability of getting out of jail through the use of rolling doubles in 3 consecutive turns, the author writes:

> We could calculate this probability in a different way. The complement of the event “roll doubles at least once over the next three turns” is “We don’t roll doubles at all over the next three turns.” Thus the probability of not rolling any doubles is (5/6) x (5/6) x (5/6) = 125/216. Since we have calculated the probability of the complement of the event that we want to find, we subtract this probability from 100%. We get the same probability of 1 – 125/216 = 91/216 that we obtained from the other method.

**I don't understand where 5/6 comes from, I calculated the probability of all sums of rolling here:**

[image: Chart]

Answer (score 1):

You can roll doubles by rolling $(1,1)$, $(2,2)$, $(3,3)$, $(4,4)$, $(5,5)$, or $(6,6)$. So there are six ways to roll doubles out of thirty six total ways to roll. Thus, the probability of rolling doubles is $1/6$. The probability of not rolling doubles is $1-1/6=5/6$.

Comment: Ah, makes sense, thank you! (:

Answer (score 0):

The sums aren't the issue, of the 36 rolls, 6 are doubles. 6/36 is 1/6 so 5/6 are not doubles.